# How to retrieve images, videos and PDF's in Firebase (Web)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, electron

I'm creating Desktop Application using electron.js with firebase database. I don't know how to retrieve multimedia data from firebase. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

B_Ali_Code, if your data model contains multimedia data then you should store it separately in Firebase Storage then have its URL stored in Firebase realtime Database. You retrieve multimedia data from your Firebase Storage through its URL, which is read from your Firebase Database.